# SQL Trigger Update is ALWAYS null

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, triggers

We are trying to make a trigger to calculate the TOTAL_COST of a Car Rental based on the number of days it has been rented. The total cost for the rental is calculated based on the number of days and the cost of the vehicle. An additional tax of 12% is added to the total. If the rental is longer than 10 days a discount of 15% is subtracted from the total cost.

This Is Our Trigger:

```
create or replace trigger L5_Q8
    After Update on E2_RESERVATIONS
    for each row
    Declare
    TOTALDAYS NUMBER(4);
    TotalCostBeforeTax Number(8);
    BEGIN
    TOTALDAYS := (trunc(:NEW.END_DATE) - TRUNC(:NEW.START_DATE)) + 1;
    IF(TOTALDAYS > 10) THEN
      SELECT V.COST_PER_DAY * TOTALDAYS * 0.85
        INTO TotalCostBeforeTax
        from E2_Reservations R
        join E2_Vehicle V on R.V_ID = V.V_ID;
    END IF;
    IF(TOTALDAYS <= 10) THEN
       SELECT V.COST_PER_DAY * TOTALDAYS
        INTO TotalCostBeforeTax
        from E2_Reservations R
        join E2_Vehicle V on R.V_ID = V.V_ID;
    END IF;
      TotalCostBeforeTax := TotalCostBeforeTax * 1.12;
      UPDATE E2_RESERVATIONS SET TOTAL_COST =  10.1 WHERE ROWID IN (SELECT MAX(ROWID) FROM E2_RESERVATIONS);
    END;
```

These are Our Tables:

E2_RESERVATIONS:

[image: E2_RESERVATIONS Table]

E2_VEHICLE:

[image: Vehicle Table]

Comment: Be careful : `TotalCostBeforeTax` must be declared as `Number(8,2)`...

Answer (score 1):

You're trying to calculate the total cost for the current record, right? So do the calculation *before* the change gets applied, not in an `after update` trigger. Also, there's way too much SQL in that trigger.

Try this:

```
create or replace trigger l5_q8
    before update on e2_reservations
    for each row
declare
    totaldays number(4);
    totalcostbeforetax number(8,2); 
begin
    -- length of reservation
    totaldays := (trunc(:new.end_date) - trunc(:new.start_date)) + 1;

    -- base cost of hire
    select v.cost_per_day * totaldays 
    into totalcostbeforetax
    from e2_vehicle v 
    where v.v_id = :new.v_id;

    -- apply discount for long reservation
    if(totaldays > 10) then
       totalcostbeforetax := totalcostbeforetax * 0.85;
    end if;

    -- apply tax to total cost
    :new.total_cost := totalcostbeforetax * 1.12;
end;
```

Note that is a BEFORE UPDATE trigger, not AFTER UPDATE.

Also, the variable `totalcostbeforetax` needs to handle decimals, because you're multiplying by 0.85, and anyway should match the declaration of the column `total_cost`.

---

> "Wouldn't you need to join the vehicle table with reservations?"

A trigger has access to all the columns of the trigger it is built on. So you're already joined to the RESERVATIONS table, by dint of `where v.v_id = :new.v_id`, which is the vehicle ID of the current reservations record.

Comment: Wouldn't you need to join the vehicle table with reservations?

With your solution its giving us a new error
 Error(13,5): PLS-00049: bad bind variable 'NEW'

We tried Changing the last few lines a little bit to get rid of the new error, it compiles but still return a null value

Comment: We're getting the same error except this time on the :new.totalcost element.

Is there another way to update the table after all calculations?

Comment: @bad22 you know the column you need to update, why can't you correct the :new.totalcost identifier name yourself? Looks like maybe it's missing an underscore?

Comment: @APC yeah we figured that out just now.

It compiles fine but its still inserting null into the column :(

Comment: We changed it to an before insert and it worked!

@APC THANK YOU!! :D

Comment: @bad22 - if this answer solved your problem you should accept it. Accepted answers improve the value of StackOverflow as a resource for other Seekers.